# Evaluation of the integral.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, integration, self-learning, residue-calculus

$$I\left(n,\epsilon\right)=\int_{-{\rm i}\infty}^{+{\rm i}\infty} \frac{{\rm e}^{\epsilon z}}{\left(z+\epsilon\right)^n}\,{\rm d}z$$

The integration is taken along the imaginary axis,

an integer $n\gt 0$ and

$\epsilon \in \left[-1, +1\right]$

How to evaluate $I\left(n, \epsilon\right)$?

I saw this question in a textbook, when I am studying. This question seems so interesting to me. Thus, I am asking here. I never have seen such question up to today. And I have No idea to solve this. Only I guess, I need to use residue theorem. Therefore, Please can someone explain and solve this clearly? I am willing to learn:) thank you so much:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take the case $\epsilon=-1$.  Then consider the following contour integral:

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{-z}}{(z-1)^n}$$

where $C$ is the semicircle of radius $R$ oriented positively, with center at the origin and diameter along the imaginary axis, closing to the right (i.e., enclosing the positive real axis).  Then we may split this contour integral into two pieces:

$$-\int_{-i R}^{i R} dz \frac{e^{-z}}{(z-1)^n} + i R \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{-R \cos{\theta}} e^{-i R \sin{\theta}}}{(R e^{i \theta}-1)^n}$$

Now, we may show that the magnitude of the second integral vanishes as $R \to \infty$ when $n \gt 0$; this magnitude is bounded by:

$$2 R \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, \frac{e^{-R \cos{\theta}}}{R^n} = \frac{2}{R^{n-1}} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-R \sin{\theta}} \le \frac{2}{R^{n-1}} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \,e^{-2 R \theta/\pi} \le \frac{\pi}{R^n}$$

By the residue theorem, the contour integral is also equal to $i 2 \pi$ times the residue at the pole $z=1$, which is

$$\frac{1}{(n-1)!} \left [\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} e^{-z} \right ]_{z=1} = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!} \frac{1}{e}$$

Therefore, we can say that

$$\int_{-i \infty}^{i \infty} dz \frac{e^{-z}}{(z-1)^n} = i 2 \pi \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n-1)!} \frac{1}{e}$$

Similarly, for $\epsilon = +1$, you can find using the above method (and being careful to orient the contour positively) that

$$\int_{-i \infty}^{i \infty} dz \frac{e^{z}}{(z+1)^n} = i 2 \pi \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: Well, I understand for $\epsilon =-1$ thanks:) but how to be careful to orient the countour positively? How and what  do I show? Can you give me an information/hint?

Comment: Orient positively means that you traverse counterclockwise along the contour.

Comment: Then, for $\epsilon =+1$  I need to write $$\int _{-iR}^{iR}dz \frac{e^z}{(z+1)^n}+2iR\int_{0}^{\pi/2} d\theta \frac{e^{R cos\theta} e^{iR sin\theta}}{(Re^{i\theta}+1)^n}$$ right?

Comment: @B11b: the second integral is not quite right.  It should go from $\pi/2$ to $3 \pi/2$ so that the cosine is negative.

Comment: Hmmm.. I couldnot think this. Dear @RonGordon if you dont mind, can you show the integrals at second part for $\epsilon =+1$? Please. Sorry I want too things. Thank you very much.

Comment: @B11b: sorry, not right now, time is limited for me.  Really, you can work this out for yourself.  Otherwise, you will not learn this.

Comment: Well, can you only write the correct integrals at the begining second and third line for $\epsilon =+1$?

Comment: @B11b: $$\int_{-i R}^{i R} dz \frac{e^{z}}{(z+1)^n} + i R \int_{\pi/2}^{3 \pi/2} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{R \cos{\theta}} e^{i R \sin{\theta}}}{(R e^{i \theta}+1)^n}$$

Comment: Okay thanks. I can continue from here. Well, this is last question. By residue theorem, you wrote an equation. For that, does there exist any important and different thing for $\epsilon =+1$ ?

Comment: @B11b: no.  Just continue the analysis the same way.

Comment: Hmm okay that's only integral calculation is different. Got it thanks a lot:) I am grateful of u:)

Comment: Hey I have a question. $$2 R \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, \frac{e^{-R \cos{\theta}}}{R^n} = \frac{2}{R^{n-1}} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, e^{-R \sin{\theta}} \le \frac{2}{R^{n-1}} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \,e^{-2 R \theta/\pi} \le \frac{\pi}{R^n}$$ why did you write first "$cos\theta $" second "$sin\theta$" ? I dont understand

Comment: @B11b: because I was interested in applying the inequality $\sin{t} \ge 2 t/\pi$, and I could make that switch with the integral.

Comment: Okay, got it:) thanks:) Dear @RonGordon

Answer (score 1):

You have a pole at $z=-\epsilon$, so pick a contour that encloses this pole. For example suppose $\epsilon=1$. It looks like a good choice is a half-circle contour whose diamater is on the imaginary axis and encloses $z=-1$. Now it's easy to show the integral vanishes on the circular part as the radius goes to infinity (note that $e^{\epsilon z}=e^{\epsilon x}e^{iy\epsilon}$ and since $\epsilon=1$, you have that $e^{\epsilon x}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow-\infty$. In particular, the denominator is enough to send the integral to 0.

Comment: Sorry, you may have shown well, but I cannot imagine what you said on my mind. Please can you be more explanatory? I dont know how to show what you said. Sorry:( I just have been learning complex analysis. Thank you:)

Comment: Take a look here for a very similar calculation: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration#Example_.28II.29_.E2.80.93_Cauchy_distribution

Comment: Okay, thanks for that guideline. Too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{{\rm e}^{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}$

> \begin{align}
> I\left(n,\epsilon\right)
> &=
> \int_{-{\rm i}\infty}^{+{\rm i}\infty} \frac{{\rm e}^{\epsilon z}}{\left(z+\epsilon\right)^n}\,{\rm d}z
> =
> \expo{-\epsilon^{2}}
> \int_{-{\rm i}\infty}^{+{\rm i}\infty}
> \frac{{\rm e}^{\epsilon\pars{z + \epsilon}}}{\left(z+\epsilon\right)^n}\,{\rm d}z
> \end{align}

1. $\large \epsilon < 0$
   \begin{align}
   I\left(n,\epsilon\right)
   &=
   \expo{-\epsilon^{2}}\pars{-2\pi\ic}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
   {\epsilon^{\ell} \over \ell!}\,
   \int_{-{\rm i}\infty}^{+{\rm i}\infty}
   {{\rm d}z \over \pars{z + \epsilon}^{n - \ell}}
   =
   \expo{-\epsilon^{2}}\pars{-2\pi\ic}
   {\epsilon^{n - 1} \over \pars{n - 1}!}\,
   \end{align}
2. $\large \epsilon > 0$
   \begin{align}
   I\left(n,\epsilon\right)
   &=
   \expo{-\epsilon^{2}}\pars{+\,2\pi\ic}\sum_{\ell = 0}^{\infty}
   {\epsilon^{\ell} \over \ell!}\,
   \int_{-{\rm i}\infty}^{+{\rm i}\infty}
   {{\rm d}z \over \pars{z + \epsilon}^{n - \ell}}
   =
   \expo{-\epsilon^{2}}\pars{+\,2\pi\ic}
   {\epsilon^{n - 1} \over \pars{n - 1}!}\,
   \end{align}
3. $\large \epsilon = 0$: Left to the OP.

> $$\color{#ff0000}{\large%
> \int_{-{\rm i}\infty}^{+{\rm i}\infty} \frac{{\rm e}^{\epsilon z}}{\left(z+\epsilon\right)^n}\,{\rm d}z
> \color{#000000}{\ =\ }
> 2\pi\ic\,{\rm sgn}^{n}\pars{\epsilon}\,
> {\verts{\epsilon}^{n -1} \over \pars{n - 1}!}\,,
> \qquad
> \color{#000000}{\epsilon \not= 0}}
> $$